# Will upgrading to 13.10 screw up my graphics drivers, and if so what can I do before upgrading to avert it?

Tags: 13.10, upgrade, ati, fglrx

I'm on Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit, with the following specs:

- CPU: AMD Athlon II x4 640
- GPU: Club3d HD 5770 1GB
- RAM: 4GB
- MOBO: GB GA-870a-USB3


  I'm currently using the regular fglrx propietary driver, but when I upgrade to 13.10 will I experience any graphics problems, and if so, how could I avert them before installing?

Answer (score 1):

I have not yet run 13.10 but I suggest that you first test your hardware with a Live media (i.e DVD, USB,etc) to see how compatible it is.